# doubleclick search report file to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to save a doubleclick search report file into GCS. I tried with the following method, but even though there is no exception, thrown the file is not saved.

```
public void saveToGCS(String reportId, String fileName) throws Exception {
        WritableByteChannel outputChannel = storageService.create(StorageResourceId.fromObjectName(fileName));
        OutputStream outputStream = Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel);
        doubleclicksearch.reports().getFile(reportId, 0).executeAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
}
```

I tried using a FileOutputStream to save it to a local location, and that worked just fine.

What's wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was SIMPLER than I thought. I just needed to close the stream at the end.